# javascript pdf table generation

Tags: javascript, jspdf-autotable

I am trying to create a pdf table in javascript. I am using **jspdf-autotable** library.

This piece of code works fine. The row item data is hard coded. 1 header row, and 2 rows of items, with 3 cells get created

```
pdf.autoTable({
    startY: finalY + 20,
    head: [['Date', 'Invoice No.', 'Description']],,
    //body: [data.itemrow],
    body: [
                ["Value A", "Value B", "Value C"],
                 ["Value A", "Value B", "Value C"],
            ],

})
```

Now, i try to dynamically pass in the row data by doing `body: [data.itemrow]`
I create a array. I do

```
 let itemrow = [];
let item = [];
item[0] = "1";
item[1] = "2";
item[2] = "3";
itemrow.push(item);
```

The problem is, `1,2,3` gets compressed into the first column. It doesn't get spread out  to all the 3 columns. how do u do it? Later I will be dynamically creating this array to pass in data read in from the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of code you shared here just looks fine, maybe it's the way you are adding the row to the doc

The `item` here you create is itself a row, so when you add this to `itemrow` array it creates array of rows

So either you can set this `itemrow` as your body, which is array of rows
Or, you can add item inside your body array

```
doc.autoTable({
    startY: finalY + 20,
    head: [['Date', 'Invoice No.', 'Description']],
    body: [
        item
    ],
});
```

OR

```
doc.autoTable({
    startY: finalY + 20,
    head: [['Date', 'Invoice No.', 'Description']],
    body: itemrow,
});
```